# Fitnesse compare large amount of text

Tags: fitnesse

My test produces a large amount of text, circa 200 lines.  When the test fails, because expected text is different to actual text, it's difficult to see where the difference is.  Is there a better way to manage this type of test?

Comment: What is your environment? Java, .NET, Slim or Fit, etc.

Comment: If you're comparing strings, you should get a message indicating where the difference is, like 'At 1 expected u was o'  Is this not happening for you? See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/CellDifferences.html

Comment: Yes it is but a difficulty is that when I copy the actual text to use as the expected text the line-ends are lost so I have to reinsert them.  I think the current failure is something to do with line ends but I cant see the issue: At 489 expected xa was x20

Comment: I got to the bottom of the problem with a bit more 'attention to detail'.  I had copied the expected and actuals into two text files and compared them using a diff tool.  This had said that they were the same because the difference was where I had line-ends. So I guess my outstanding question is: why copying from the fitness page loses the line-ends.

Comment: An approach I've used in the past is to keep the expected text in a file and write a 'checkFile' method to compare the actual and expected files.  This avoids any problems with how Fitnesse is handling line terminators.